# Is there an example of a topological space which is perfectly normal and Lindelöf but not metacompact?

Tags: general-topology

As the title says, I am trying to find an example of a topological space which is, [perfectly normal](http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Perfectly_normal_space), [Lindelöf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindel%C3%B6f_space), but not [metacompact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacompact_space).
Can anyone help me with an example for such a space, or if there isn't, show why?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, every regular Lindelöf space is paracompact (which clearly implies metacompact).

Here is a proof:

> Suppose $X$ is a regular Lindelöf space.  Given an open cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $X$, for each $x \in X$ we can choose open neighbourhoods $U_x , V_x$ of $x$ such that $\overline{V}_x \subseteq U_x$, and $U_x \in \mathcal{U}$.  Then by Lindelöfness there are $\{ x_i : i \in \mathbb{N} \}$ such that $\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} V_{x_i} = X$.  For $i \in \mathbb{N}$ set $$W_i = U_{x_i} \setminus {\textstyle \bigcup_{j<i}} \overline{V_{x_j}}.$$  Clearly each $W_i \subseteq U_{x_i}$ is open.  To see that it covers $X$, given $x \in X$ let $i \in \mathbb{N}$ be least such that  $x \in U_{x_i}$, and note that $x \in W_i$.  To see that it is locally finite, given $x \in X$ let $i \in \mathbb{N}$ be such that $x \in V_{x_i}$, and note that $V_{x_i} \cap W_j = \varnothing$ for all $j > i$.

Comment: ok got it. Thank you!!